# Code doesn't run when instancing multiple objects from the same class, but does work when instancing objects from a duplicate class with the same code

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, ld, riscv

**Solved!**
The issue a similar name in my bootscript my main source file. Look at the answer for more details.

I've had this mind-boggling error for weeks now. I am compiling for the GD32V chip.
What happens is, I have the following class, which abstracts the gpio pin output for the chip:

```
 class pin_out : public hwlib::pin_out
{
    private:
    const pin_info_type & myPin;
    bool status;
    public:
        pin_out(pins pin_number) : myPin(pin_info_array[(int)pin_number]){
            rcu_periph_clock_enable(myPin.enable_register); 
            
            gpio_init(myPin.port, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP, GPIO_OSPEED_50MHZ, myPin.pin);
            gpio_bit_reset(myPin.port, myPin.pin);
            status=0;
        } 

        void write(bool x){
            
           if(x){
               status=1;
               gpio_bit_set(myPin.port,  myPin.pin);
           }else{
               gpio_bit_reset(myPin.port, myPin.pin);
               status=0;
           }
        }

        void flush(){
            // Empty
        }

        void toggle(){
            status=!status;
            write(status);
        }

};
```

This works great, I can make a pin and call 'pin.write(1)' and 'pin.write(0)' as many times as I want and it works. However, as soon as I instance 2 pins, i.e. pin1 and pin2... it doesn't matter if I write to the second pin or not, my code just doesn't run. However, now the funny part, if I copy/paste this pin_out class and rename it and instance 2 objects from these different classes, it does run again.

Here's how this class looks:

```
 class test_pin_out{
private:
   const  pin_info_type & myPin;
public:
    test_pin_out(pins pin_number) : myPin(pin_info_array[(int)pin_number]){
         rcu_periph_clock_enable(myPin.enable_register); 
            
            gpio_init(myPin.port, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP, GPIO_OSPEED_50MHZ, myPin.pin);
            gpio_bit_reset(myPin.port, myPin.pin); 
    }
void write(bool x){
            
           if(x){
               gpio_bit_set(myPin.port,  myPin.pin);
           }else{
               gpio_bit_reset(myPin.port, myPin.pin);
           }
        }

};
```

And then I use this main:

```
#include "hwlib.hpp"
int main(void)
{

  hwlib::target::pin_out pin1 = hwlib::target::pin_out(hwlib::target::pins::led_blue);
  hwlib::target::test_pin_out pin2 = hwlib::target::test_pin_out(hwlib::target::pins::led_green);
  while(true){
   pin1.write(1);
   pin2.write(1);
  }



 return 0;
 }
```

I am using the official [manufacturer's header files](https://www.gigadevice.com/microcontroller/gd32vf103c8t6/).
Myself I am suspecting some optimization issue that happens within the device headers, as my code so far only runs with O2 and O3 optimization(not lower or higher).

Does anyone have any clue as to where I might have to look or how I can resolve this issue?

EDIT:
As response to the replies, here is the class I inherit from. Hwlib::pin_out

```
    class pin_out : public noncopyable {
public:

   /// @copydoc pin_in_out::write()  
   virtual void write( bool x ) = 0;  
   
   /// @copydoc pin_in_out::flush() 
   virtual void flush() = 0; 

};
```

And the class this class inherits from:

```
class noncopyable {
public:   
   noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
   noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
   constexpr noncopyable() {}
   // ~noncopyable() {} // somehow requires the heap??
};
```

Comment: Forgive me but your `test_pin_out` class is not the same as your `pin_out` class. In particular your `pin_out` class inherits from `hwlib::pin_out` but `test_pin_out` does not.

Comment: What does the docu for the type you inherit from have to say about 1) being inherited from, 2) being instantiated more than once.

Comment: @john yes true, it doesn't inherit. pin_out is simply an abstract class. It doesn't add functionality. I'll add it to the question though :)

Comment: I would strongly advise against writing generic wrappers around GPIO. Thousands before you have tried, thousands before you have failed. It adds lots of bloat, lag and bugs but nothing of value. Instead you should probably write a driver for a project-specific piece of hardware which is using GPIO. Because... GPIO isn't rocket science. Set a data direction register. Set a pull resistor register. Optionally enable interrupts. Access a port register. That's it.

Comment: @Lundin this is part of a bigger project, specific for students, to help them teach them about embedded. It works flawlessly for a number of chips already, it's just this risc-v that's showing issues. I am working on this to learn more about hardware abstraction and low-level bare-metal programming, whether or not it adds bloats isn't really relevant for me currently

Comment: @Vvamp Students should learn to use the raw registers and hardware peripherals, instead of learning to rely on libraries written by others. Otherwise you are teaching them how some specific libraries work, not how microcontrollers work. Sure, you might get some blinking lights up and running faster with a pre-made library. But then you haven't learnt much.

Comment: @Lundin I partially disagree, but this discussion is completely irrelevant to my question. If you want to continue this discussion, it'd be better to do it via chat. I simply need help with this question for my own personal development and if you disagree with that, that's fine, but my reasons are mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it!
The one thing I didn't expect to be the issue, was the issue.

Basically I had the linkerscript calling the bootscript. I grabbed these two files from a blogpost. However, the linkerscript called the bootscript's function, which was named 'main'. As my own function in my source file was also called 'main', something went wrong.
So only my source's main function got called and not my bootscript, which meant my bss wasn't being reset to 0, which caused undefined behaviour.

Stupid on my part to not look into this, but I'm still quite new to all of this.